# IIS email blocked by anti virus

Tags: iis

I have being having trouble with the web server used for our intranet. It has some antivirus software on it that stops mass emailing.

So I wrote a quick C# winforms app, ran it on the server to try and send an email, and it failed. It was being blocked by antivirus on the server, I added the exe to the allowed list and it worked fine. I tried adding the service `inetinfo.exe`, which is the only one I could see related to IIS, and it doesn't seem to enable the emailing.

Would asp.net code send the email under a different exe name? I have seen a reference to `aspnet_wp.exe`.

Comment: doesn't the av log show which process has been blocked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET runs under "w3wp.exe" on Windows Server 2003, and "aspnet_wp.exe" under Windows 2000.  So you'll need to open up your scanner for those processes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added port 25 or whatever the smtp server is using to the allow list?